# How to retrieve data stored in bytea format

Tags: postgresql

I have the data in form of json/xml but in the database it is stored in form of bytea, how can i extract it back in form of json/xml.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT request_payload FROM unirate_incoming_request WHERE id='1224892672'
```

Output i am getting:

```
   [
  org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42ResultSet@119020fb
]
```

Here is my database query:

```
public ResultSet payload(String a) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet dboutput;
        String query = " SELECT request_payload FROM unirate_incoming_request WHERE id='1224892672';
        System.out.println(query);
        DatabaseConnection dc = new DatabaseConnection(server, dbName, user, password);
        dboutput = dc.executeQuery1(query);
        System.out.println("hi");
        while (dboutput.next()) {
            System.out.print(dboutput.getBytes("request_payload") + "   ");
        }
        dboutput.close();
        dc.close();
        return dboutput;
    }
```

Here is my database connection:

```
public ResultSet executeQuery1(String sql) throws SQLException {
        logSql(sql);
        Statement stmt = createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        return rs;
    }
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: i am using java

Comment: Then you need to use `ResultSet.getBytes()` and turn those bytes into a String. By why aren't you storing that in a `jsonb`, `xml` or at least a `text` column?

Comment: i am not getting the json still, i have added my database connection and query